# How to make Gtk.ListBoxRow accept right clicks on any area?

Tags: user-interface, gtk3, vala

**Edit**: corrected code.

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox ();
ListBoxRow row = new ListBoxRow ();
row.add (new Label ("Test row"));
row.button_release_event.connect ((event) => {
    if (event.button == 3) {
        debug ("Right button clicked.\n");
    }
    return false;
});
listBox.add (row);
```

Doesn't work. Prints nothing. But this other one works fine

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox ();
ListBoxRow row = new ListBoxRow ();
row.add (new CheckButton.with_label ("Test row"));
row.button_release_event.connect ((event) => {
    if (event.button == 3) {
        debug ("Right button clicked.\n");
    }
    return false;
});
listBox.add (row);
```

as it prints the debug message. Is it possible to handle right clicks on the ListBoxRow on any area, regardless of what its children are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option to solve this problem would be to use an Gtk.EventBox as the immediate child of each Gtk.ListBoxRow and then use the EventBox as the container for the rows content:

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox ();
ListBoxRow row = new ListBoxRow ();
EventBox box = new EventBox ();
box.add (new Label ("Test row"));
row.add (box);
row.button_release_event.connect ((event) => {
    if (event.button == 3) {
        debug ("Right button clicked.\n");
    }
    return false;
});
listBox.add (row);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works very neatly. Right, append_val isn't a method of ListBox. I mixed it with a GLib.Array I had when asking my question. I'll edit the question and fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @g_l Ok, I'll remove the side note. Good luck

Comment: It's okay, you don't have to remove it. You can if you want though. :)

Comment: @g_l It's better. It's just noise in the question/answer. Thanks ;) GL

Comment: Ok. I'll change my edit head note as well then to match the flow. Done.